# Elastic Search, use scripted field for an aggregation result

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-painless

I would like to know if it is possible to have a `scripted_field` in the result of an aggregation:

An example query:

```
GET /index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "agg": {
    "test": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "key"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The result I would like to archive is the following:

```
{
    "aggregations": {
        "test": {
            "buckets": [
                {
                    "key": "key1",
                    "doc_count": 10,
                    "new value": // can be filled via a plainless script.
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, scripted fields are not accessible from within the aggregations because they constitute separate contexts/[parts of the API](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/how-to-use-a-script-field-inside-aggregate/191190/2).

What you can use instead is [script terms aggregations](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation-script) (what you're most probably looking for) or [scripted metric aggregations](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-scripted-metric-aggregation.html).

---

EDIT

You cannot modify the structure/syntax of the response but you can have globally shared agg [metadata](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/agg-metadata.html). If you need more info, expound on your question w/ a concrete use case, mapping & data.